# sql server set consumption value based on first older record

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

i have a table containing sensor data in Sql server 2014, with multiple sensors each with its own sensor id. I want to calculate and set / update the consumption field by calculating the consumption between the current value and subtracting the previous value based on the logdate for a single sensorid, for example sensorid = 8555.

Current table structure for sensorid 8555:

```
+----------+-------------------------+---------+-------------+
| SensorId |         LogDate         |  Value  | Consumption |
+----------+-------------------------+---------+-------------+
|     8555 | 2016-10-03 13:00:00.000 | 0.00000 |     Null    |
|     2478 | 2016-11-09 09:00:00.000 | 0.00000 |     0.00000 |
|     2478 | 2016-11-09 10:00:00.000 | 0.00000 |     0.00000 |
|     8555 | 2016-10-03 14:00:00.000 | 1.00000 |     Null    |
|     8555 | 2016-10-03 15:00:00.000 | 1.00000 |     Null    |
|     8555 | 2016-10-03 16:00:00.000 | 1.00000 |     Null    |
|     8555 | 2016-10-03 17:00:00.000 | 2.00000 |     Null    |
|     8555 | 2016-10-03 18:00:00.000 | 2.00000 |     Null    |
|     8555 | 2016-10-03 19:00:00.000 | 4.00000 |     Null    |
+----------+-------------------------+---------+-------------+
```

The end result should be this:

```
+----------+-------------------------+---------+-------------+
| SensorId |         LogDate         |  Value  | Consumption |
+----------+-------------------------+---------+-------------+
|     8555 | 2016-10-03 13:00:00.000 | 0.00000 |     0.00000 |
|     2478 | 2016-11-09 09:00:00.000 | 0.00000 |     0.00000 |
|     2478 | 2016-11-09 10:00:00.000 | 0.00000 |     0.00000 |
|     8555 | 2016-10-03 14:00:00.000 | 1.00000 |     1.00000 |
|     8555 | 2016-10-03 15:00:00.000 | 1.00000 |     0.00000 |
|     8555 | 2016-10-03 16:00:00.000 | 1.00000 |     0.00000 |
|     8555 | 2016-10-03 17:00:00.000 | 2.00000 |     1.00000 |
|     8555 | 2016-10-03 18:00:00.000 | 2.00000 |     0.00000 |
|     8555 | 2016-10-03 19:00:00.000 | 4.00000 |     2.00000 |
+----------+-------------------------+---------+-------------+
```

I have scoured google for a solution, and i could only find a version of the answer for Mysql, which i do not know how to convert to sql server.
I know that the update statement should contain LAG and probably use CTEs but i haven't found an easy to understand explanation on how to use those on the web.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BEGIN TRAN

```
CREATE TABLE #T (SensorId INT , LogDate  DATETIME, Value DECIMAL(15,4), Consumption DECIMAL(15,4))
INSERT INTO #T
SELECT     8555 ,  '2016-10-03 13:00:00.000'  ,0.00000 ,Null     UNION ALL   
SELECT     2478 ,  '2016-11-09 09:00:00.000'  ,0.00000 ,0.0000   UNION ALL  
SELECT     2478 ,  '2016-11-09 10:00:00.000'  ,0.00000 ,0.0000   UNION ALL
SELECT     8555 ,  '2016-10-03 14:00:00.000'  ,1.00000 ,Null     UNION ALL  
SELECT     8555 ,  '2016-10-03 15:00:00.000'  ,1.00000 ,Null     UNION ALL
SELECT     8555 ,  '2016-10-03 16:00:00.000'  ,1.00000 ,Null     UNION ALL
SELECT     8555 ,  '2016-10-03 17:00:00.000' ,2.00000  ,Null     UNION ALL
SELECT     8555 ,  '2016-10-03 18:00:00.000' ,2.00000  ,Null     UNION ALL
SELECT     8555 ,  '2016-10-03 19:00:00.000' ,4.00000  ,Null     


GO
SELECT * FROM  #T  
;with CTE as (
    select SensorId,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order By SensorId,LogDate) Rownum,
        LogDate, Value
    FROM #T  
  )

UPDATE #T SET Consumption= ISNULL(curr.Value - prev.Value,0)
from #T INNER JOIN
CTE curr ON  #T.LogDate= curr.LogDate
left join CTE prev on curr.Rownum = (prev.Rownum + 1)


SELECT * FROM #T
ROLLBACK TRAN
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Alfaiz, using a select statement i know how to calculate the consumption, the problem is i want to update the table and write the consumption values back into the table.

Comment: @lazylorax Updated The query check it.

Comment: Hi Alfaiz, i made a bad representation of data. I have multiple sensorids in the same table, and the rownumbers can be mixed, for example there may be 50 rows of sensorid 4588 and then 3 rows of 8555 and then lets say 32 rows of sensorid 5948 etc. What would be a query that would update the consumption values for only one sensorid? I tried your query with a "WHERE SensorId = 8555, but that gives me the wrong values.

Comment: @lazylorax I had just modify The query can you check I'm getting the Desire OUTPUT as you Mention Above

Comment: Hi, this now goes over the whole table and updates all the sensors, i wish to update only a specific sensorid.

Comment: IN Where Clause you pass The Sensor ID Which you wan't to update

Comment: Can this be optimized in some way? the query works but it reads out the whole table (in my case a few gigabytes) and takes forever just to update 20 rows.

Comment: But When I'm running The Query Getting The Data Updated in 0 seconds

Comment: Yes, in a table with only 20 rows. My table has a few million rows, and with the following query : SELECT * FROM  #T  
;with CTE as (
    select SensorId,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order By SensorId,LogDate) Rownum,
        LogDate, Value
    FROM #T
 Where sensorid = 8555  
  )

UPDATE #T SET Consumption= curr.Value - prev.Value
from #T
INNER JOIN
CTE curr ON  #T.LogDate= curr.LogDate
left join CTE prev on curr.Rownum = (prev.Rownum + 1)
it takes around 30 minutes

Comment: Sorry, i'm an idiot... I copied your code without looking at it and i also copied the SELECT * FROM  #T  statement, which ran before the query i actually need :). Thank you so much, i still don't understand how this works but it gives the results i need.

Comment: @lazylorax Welcome Bro.